# Ui router AngularJs Nested states and Nested views correct way

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**here's the repo:** https://github.com/vipul-verma/LetsLearnAngular

**here's the live view:** https://rawgit.com/vipul-verma/LetsLearnAngular/master/index.html

**Explanation:**
A basic template.

Home link will load the **partials/home.html**.

About link will load the **partials/about.html** and **partials/about-sublevel.html.**

**Problem:**

Here **partials/about-sublevel.html** is a sub level of about page so it can be said its a part of about page or **nested view/state** of about page. But if you see the index page it has two views **'viewA'** , **'viewB'**.

**'viewA'** loads **partials/home.html** or **partials/about.html** according to link.

**'viewB'** loads only when About link is clicked with **partials/about-sublevel.html.**

**Question:**

Is there a way to separate the  **partials/about-sublevel.html** page from **index page** and **load inside about.html** so I don't have to put the tag in **index page** as **`<div ui-view="viewB"></div>`**.

**Correct way** 
'viewB' should **load inside about.html** since its a part of about page and when i click on about link both **partials/about.html** and **partials/about-sublevel.html** are displayed by default.

What is the correct way, Best practice in this scenario.  What will be done in **app.js** to achieve this. Please give answer using the above git repo only and please. please don't give dummy answers without using the code from repo. Thank you

Comment: Can you make a plunker for that?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question. Can't you put the 2 templates together? Best practice is for every route 1 template.

Comment: here's the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7BgBWeSStMuIrYBR3tS?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I don't understand your question completely, but the best practice would be to have 1 template for every state.

Here is an example of how I work with nested views:

```
 var root = "/app/Views/";

    $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: root + 'Index.html'
        })
        .state('pas', {
            url: '/pas',
            templateUrl: root + 'Index.html'
        })

        .state('pas.calculate', {
            url: '/calculate',
            templateUrl: root + 'Calculate.html'
        })
        .state('pas.calculate.form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: root + 'Calculate/Form.html'
        })
        .state('pas.calculate.overview', {
            url: '/overview',
            templateUrl: root + 'Calculate/Overview.html'
        })

        .state('pas.contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: root + 'Contact.html'
        })

    $stateProvider
        .state("otherwise", {
            url: "*path",
            templateUrl: root + "Index.html"
        });
```

Comment: without reading the post you say i don't understand and down vote my post easy hunff

Comment: Well, I did read it, but I think I don't understand the issue. I did not downvote btw. Guess other people had the same thoughts..

Comment: pls see this link here i asked the same thing ..answers says use ng-include but nested states are also possible but how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795051/angular-js-ui-router-nested-views/35795385#35795385