# angular Js ui router nested views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

link to example: http://goo.gl/jJBMZL

Here two states are defined. 1. home , 2. about

home has 1 view viewA

about has 2 views viewA and viewB but viewB is a sub part of about page. I want to show viewB inside of about.html page and not on index page. Is this possible. Please provide a plunkr link thanks.

what is the best practice if there are various views  and each view has sub states

Comment: There is literally a section on this in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#nested-states--views)

Comment: not able to understand from that its complicated. can you give a simple answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your page 'about-sub-level.html' inside 'about.html' using ng-include like as-

```
<h1>I am about page</h1>
<div ng-include="'about-sub-level.html'"> </div>
```

Change your routing like below-

```
 .state('about', {
            url: "/about",
            views: {
                "viewA": {
                    templateUrl: "about.html"
                }
            }
        })
```

Hope this may help you..

Comment: ok this works but is it possible to give states for about say about.sub-about...so that i do not have to give ng-include. I mean nested states for about page.. i know its possible but its complicated in documentation. i am not able to get that. Pls give demo for that way also